# Custom recipe order: launch before server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I need to generate some config files on deploy but server won't start before I do that.

I managed to get custom recipes to work and put them into **Deploy** group but they're being run after server restart.

How do I make my recipes run on deploy before the unicorn restart task?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is use the deployment hooks available to you on Opsworks. REF:  [deployment hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-hooks.html) Specific one you need to use for this is : deploy/before_restart.rb

Comment: I have used the **before_migrate.rb** hook as I needed to procompile assets as well. Works great! Thank you!